# Background color for confluence page

Tags: html, css, confluence

I'm creating a confluence page and want to set a background color for the page.
I have inserted "Css Style sheet" and have added below

```
body{
background-color: #E6E6FA; 
}
```

When the page loads the color loads and was getting overwritten.
any ideas how to set the color.

Comment: Body background color override by many different factors. Its always great to provide full code so we can understand the exact problem. So I request, please provide full code and read the Stackoverflow guidelines before asking any new question. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Please share you code.

Comment: Thats the complete code i added inside CSS Macro. If you go to confluence and add CSS , you will understand the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am able to update the background color using below tag

```
.wiki-content{
background-color: #E6E6FA; 
}
```

Comment: Not a useful answer, as wiki-content is not a universal class for all the world wide users. Its always great to add question along with full code snippet. I encourage you to just go and check the stackoverflow guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/tour